# Encode strings into bytes and then decode back into strings

Tags: solidity

My goal is to **encode** two strings into `bytes` with this function:

```
function encode(string memory _address1, string memory _address2) public  returns (bytes memory) {
        encoded = abi.encodePacked(_address1, _address2);
        return encoded;

    }
```

And then I want to **decode** the bytes back into individual strings:

```
function decode(bytes memory _encoded) public pure returns (string memory x, string memory y) {
       return abi.decode(_encoded, (string, string));
    }
```

However, when I feed the bytes from the `encode` function, I get the following error:

```
call to ERC721ReceiverMock.decode errored: VM error: revert.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the `decode` function it is required that the data is ABI encoded (the details for this can be found in the [Solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/abi-spec.html)). But `encodePacked` does not do so, it actually performs a packed encoding, which omits meta information about the encoded data (e.g. the length of the strings). More on this can also be found in the [Solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/abi-spec.html?highlight=encodepacked#non-standard-packed-mode).

To encode your data in a way that follows the ABI spec you need use `abi.encode` (instead of `abi.encodePacked`). So your code would change to

```js
function encode(string memory _address1, string memory _address2) public  returns (bytes memory) {
   encoded = abi.encode(_address1, _address2);
   return encoded;
}
```

Edit: Here the link to the [docs for `abi.encode`](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=abi.encode(...)#abi-encoding-and-decoding-functions)